# .JPG attachment is received as .File in android email

Tags: android

This is part of my code (given below) which I am using to send image as an attachment in email from my android application, it works fine but the received image is of type `File` instead of `JPG`. So please tell how can I set the type of image attached in email.

**Code:**

```
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setSubject(subject);
Address address = new InternetAddress(from,sender);
message.setFrom(address);
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));
MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
String file = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+ File.separator+"test"+".jpg";
messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
String fileName = "Attached Image";
DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
messageBodyPart.setFileName(fileName);
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
message.setContent(multipart);
Transport.send(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have working code for sending mail with attached file,

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("text/html");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "File attached");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "image.png"));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

Let me know if you need any other help.